# Comparing two IPv6 addresses and their masks (windows)

Tags: c++, ip-address, equals, ipv6, mask

I have to compare two IPv6 addresses and their masks to see if they are the same. They are both in strings, such as "xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/xx". I would just use memcmp to compare them bit by bit, however this may return false when true, due to the fact that xxxx:xxxx:0000:xxxx/xx and xxxx:xxxxx::xxxxx/xx are technically the same address.

I would prefer not to create substrings of the addresses and masks, but I will if there's a function that compares two IPv6 addresses. Any suggestions? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should convert both addressed to binary form using `inet_pton` and then compare the binary forms (which are just 16 bytes of data you can compare with `memcmp`).

If you need to compare masked addresses then you will have to do a little more work. `inet_pton` will not parse prefix lengths ("/something") for you so you will have to:

1. Find the slash
2. Pass the part before the slash to `inet_pton`
3. Parse the integer after the slash with plain ol' `atoi`
4. Manually zero out 128 minus that number of bits at the end of the binary form of the address

...on each address before comparing them.

Comment: Why is the fourth step needed? Once I have the addresses in binary form, shouldn't I already be able to call memcmp to test if their equal?

Comment: In your question you implied that you wanted to consider prefix lengths in the matching, so that for example ::1234:5678:9abc/128 and ::1234:5678:def0/128 would be unequal (compares all 128 bits) whereas ::1234:5678:9abc/112 and ::1234:5678:def0/112 would be equal (because of the /112 prefix length, the last 16 bits don't count). To achieve that, you have to zero out the bits that don't count.

Comment: How to do 4th step? Can not do bit shift on in6_addr ?

Comment: @AJ.: You will need to treat each 8-bit group independantly. You may do 8 operations, either completely zero-ing out a byte, not touching it, or zeroing out its lower bits, according to its position and the number of bits you need to zero out. Yes, it's tedious because C has no 128-bit integer type.

Answer (score 1):

As usual, do not reinvent the wheel. The excellent libcidr library does what you want and more.   http://www.over-yonder.net/~fullermd/projects/libcidr

Comment: Cool!, somehow no amount of search from any search engine pointed me to libcidr!!, thanks for making a reference.

Answer (score 0):

I would still suggest using substrings since they are fairly easy to extract. Then, you could overload string's equals() function to return true when comparing "0000" and "", and any other corner cases you might run into.

Comment: There are ***way*** too many cases for this to be a viable option: 0, 00, 000, and 0000 are all equal, :: collapses any number of 16-bit groups of zero bits and it may be located differently in each address, there's uppercase and lowercase hex digits, addresses like ::ffff:1.2.3.4 which is the same as ::ffff:102:304, and more.

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass both addresses through a function which would convert them to the same format. After that you can compare them as strings.

The function example:

```
string Ip6(const string& data) {
    struct in6_addr ip6;
    if (inet_pton(AF_INET6, data.c_str(), &ip6) != 1)
        throw str::runtime_error("bad ivp6 address");

    char buf[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    return inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &ip6, buf, sizeof(buf));
}
```